# JS arrays merge and sum

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have arrays

```
{"BS-WHITE":3,"BS-BOX":1}//input value
{"BS-WHITE":2,"BS-BOX":0,"BS-WHITE-1":1}//output value
```

And I would like to merge them to get arrays in array something like this:

```
[["BS-WHITE",3,2],["BS-BOX",1,0],["BS-WHITE-1",0,1]]
```

If value doesn't exist should be 0.

Comment: Your output is not valid JS syntax. You need to use `[]` for arrays not `{}`

Comment: updated. hope OK now:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear if you want an output object or array.

Anyways..You can try something like below.

If you need an output array.

```js
a = {"BS-WHITE":3,"BS-BOX":1}//input value
b = {"BS-WHITE":2,"BS-BOX":0,"BS-WHITE-1":1}

c = [...new Set([...Object.keys(a), ...Object.keys(b)])];

result = c.map((key) => {
   return  {
        [key]: [(a[key] || 0), (b[key] || 0)] 
    }   
});

console.log(result);
```

If you need an output object.

```js
a = {"BS-WHITE":3,"BS-BOX":1}//input value
b = {"BS-WHITE":2,"BS-BOX":0,"BS-WHITE-1":1}

c = [...new Set([...Object.keys(a), ...Object.keys(b)])];

result = c.reduce((acc,key) => {
        acc[key] = [(a[key] || 0), (b[key] || 0)] 
        return acc;
  
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

If you need array of arrays

```js
a = {"BS-WHITE":3,"BS-BOX":1}//input value
b = {"BS-WHITE":2,"BS-BOX":0,"BS-WHITE-1":1}

c = [...new Set([...Object.keys(a), ...Object.keys(b)])];

result = c.map(key => {
        return [key , (a[key] || 0), (b[key] || 0)]
  
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: thank you the second option is much cleaner. I wouldn't be better to make simple nested array. It means - maybe it would be easier to loop.

Comment: @awariat Updated the answer. See the third option.